# Help with reading a scheme for car locking control box Peugeot 306 1997

Tags: locks, peugeot

I have Peugeot 306 from 1997 and I have a problem with the locking system. When I'm trying to lock the car it attempts to lock all doors, but then immediately unlocks all doors. I had a problem with the door loom, which my dad decided to cut of and just connect all the wires (I know it's a very bad try to fix the things) everything seems to work after the fix except the locks.

In some forums people says that the work around is to curquit the two pins responsible for the "check if the door is closed".

The problem is that in all articles the control box is black with two cable connectors, but not in my case. Mine is a gray box with one connector with 9 pins. I managed to find the electrical scheme of the box, but I need some help with reading it:

[image]

Thank you!

The box is with number **H97 9611914080** if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean by “curquit”?

Comment: @SolarMike like to connect some of the pins. I was looking here, but this guy have the other type of control box. And the information about these cars is not so updated http://www.nickhill.co.uk/peugeot_306_central_locking_popping_up.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pins 5,7,8 on the control box connect to the lock position sensors on the two front doors.

the modification he describes would be equivalent to connecting pins 7 and 8 on your controller and disconnecting one of the lock position sensors, (I'm guessing passenger side)

Comment: Thank you Jasen, these are the correct pins. But maybe in my case the problem will be somewhere else, because it's still don't work. Searching continues.